# tailwind css problem, how can i give space between these divs, the text is too close to the image

Tags: tailwind-css

I have a problem with my tailwind CSS spacing between the text and the image.

[These are the images when the text is long](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EChnt.jpg)

[This is the image of the when i tried to separate them](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9dj7N.jpg)

I basically tried to give it space between but then nothing really happened, ideally, I would have some space to give negative space to the image but anything i do is preventing it from happening.

Here is the code below:

```js
import Image from 'next/image';

const HeroSection = () => {   
  return (
    <section className="text-gray-600 body-font bg-white dark:bg-slate-900">
      <div className="container mx-auto flex  md:px-24 md:py-10 md:flex-row flex-col items-center">
        <div className="lg:flex-grow mt-5 md:mt-0 md:w-1/2 lg:pr-24 md:pr-16 flex flex-col md:items-start mb-16 md:mb-0">
          <h1 className="text-left text-2xl font-bold lg:pl-20 leading-9 tracking-tight mb-3 text-gray-900 dark:text-gray-100 sm:text-4xl sm:leading-10 md:text-5xl md:leading-normal">
            Cebu's most reliable aircon services
          </h1>
          <p className="mb-8 md:pl-12 lg:pl-52 leading-relaxed dark:text-gray-300 text-left">
            Short description here, Short description here Short description here Short description here Short description here Short description here.
          </p>
          <div className="flex justify-start">
          <a href="#" className="ml-4 mr-2 mt-2 inline-flex text-gray-700 bg-gray-100 border-0 py-2 px-6 focus:outline-none hover:bg-gray-200 rounded text-lg">
              Read articles
            </a>
            <a href="#" className="ml-4 mt-2 inline-flex text-gray-700 bg-gray-100 border-0 py-2 px-6 focus:outline-none hover:bg-gray-200 rounded text-lg">
              Read articles
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="lg:max-w-lg lg:w-full mb-5 md:mb-0 md:w-1/2 w-3/6">
          <Image
            src="/hero-image.png"
            alt="hero"
            width={600}
            height={600}
            className="object-cover object-center rounded"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
}

export default HeroSection;
```

Comment: give gap class to parent of the text and image div

Comment: You doesn't need to add `padding` when you are use `flex` because of we can set spacing using `gap-[YourValue]` class. `gap` is work with `flex`, `grid` and `flex-box` .

So in your code I have added `gap-16` class in first child of section tag that add 64px of spacing between both elements.

`<div className="container mx-auto flex gap-16 md:px-24 md:py-10 md:flex-row flex-col items-center">`